# Cursor appears in two edittexts when using request focus inside focus change listener

Tags: android

I have 3 EditTexts(E1, E2 and E3). I am using a validation at the time of focus lost from E2. (ie. E1 and E2 are number fields. E2's value shouldn't be greater than E1). So am checking the validation at the lost focus of E2.

The problem is after checking validation the cursor appears in E3 and also in E2, and the typing appears in E3.

I want to retain the cursor only in E2 after validation if validation fails(valued of E2 > value of E2). Below given the code i used.

```
e2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                if(Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString() > Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString()){
                    e2.requestFocus();
                    e2.setSelection(e2.getText().toString().length());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I don't know is it a valid question. Anyway i am stuck in this problem. Please help me to recover this.

Comment: etNetSales.getText().toString().length() is that e3?

Comment: @Rajashree Tiwari. sorry it is e2. I used it to set the cursor place to the last of text in e2.

Comment: check the condition :- if(e2Value<e3Value){ e3.requestFocus();

Comment: Sorry to say, i didn't get any solution to the exact problem. So i partially resolved the stuck by changing the scenario. ie. I ignored the e2.requestFocus() and put an alert to user regarding the difference and put the value of e1 to e2. And the cursor will go to the next field(e3).

*NB - I just put this comment as Alternate solution, please ignore if not.

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically set the edit text cursor with:

```
editText.setSelection(int)
```

Comment: What does this do? Please explain.